# A box for codes including verbatim

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to crate an ‎environment aligning with text margin for Matlab codes like this:
[image]

In this image I used to a box, with `\begin{verbatim} .... \end{verbatim}`, however it is not aligning with text margin.
Some tools are provided, however, I cant assemble them.

```
\documentclass{article}‎
‎\usepackage{tikz}‎
‎\RequirePackage[framemethod=‎TikZ‎]{‎mdframed}    

% ‎Matlab‎ box
\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt‎, ‎skipbelow=7pt‎,
backgroundcolor=black!5‎, ‎linecolor=ocre‎, ‎innerleftmargin=5pt‎,
innerrightmargin=5pt‎, ‎innertopmargin=5pt‎, ‎leftmargin=0cm‎,
rightmargin=0cm‎,‎‎ roundcorner=‎5‎‎‎pt,‎
innerbottommargin=5pt]{‎m‎Box}‎‎

‎‎‎\‎newenvironment{matlabcode}{\begin{mBox}??????\end{mBox}}
% including verbatim (if it is possible)
\begin{document}    

\begin{matlabcode}
  a = w*f;
  k = sin(x);
\end{matlabcode}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try tcolorbox with its listing library.